# Why does shallow Rendering not work as expected?

Tags: unit-testing, reactjs, enzyme, airbnb-js-styleguide

I am using enzyme for test my `create-react-app` component, but It did not work intuitively.
Am I misunderstanding what shallow rendering is?

```
import React from "react";
import { Card } from "./Card";

const TestUser = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="test" />
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Card />
        <Card />
        <Card />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestUser;
```

.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import TestUser from "./TestUser";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { Card } from "./Card";

it("should render right", () => {
  const component = shallow(<TestUser />);
  expect(component.find(Card)).to.have.length(3);
});
```

I expect it should pass the test, cause it does have 3 `Card` components in `TestUser`

But it output:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'have' of undefined

How does that work?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem. It solved by using the below .

I have created a `jest.config.js` file at the root level and add below code.

```
module.export ={
  setupFiles:[ '<rootDir>/src/setUpTests.js']
 }
```

I have created `setUpTests.js` file and add below code.

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

And solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out. You have to give it as a string literal. Also to me the `expect` library you are using is not the one you get from `chai` and may have different set of helper methods, hence giving that error. Unfortunately I don't have the code with me to check further. Nothing wrong with shallow rendering at all.

```
import React from "react";
import TestUser from "./TestUser";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import { expect } from 'chai';

it("should render right", () => {
  const component = shallow(<TestUser />);
  expect(component.find('Card')).to.have.length(3);
});
```

Also you don't need to have this statement here, `import Card from "./card";`

In the TestUser component change the import statement like this.

```
import Card from "./card";
```

So now your `TestUser` component should look like this.

```
import React from "react";
import Card from "./card";

const TestUser = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="test" />
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Card />
        <Card />
        <Card />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TestUser;
```

Use the following command to install `chai` library.

```
npm install --save chai
```

If you really want to use Jest change your assertion as below.

```
import React from "react";
import TestUser from "./testuser";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

it("should render right", () => {
  const component = shallow(<TestUser />);
  expect(component.find('Card')).toHaveLength(3);
});
```

Personally I like mocha due to it's fluent API.

Hope this helps. Happy coding !

Comment: I am using `create-react-app`. [enzyme doc](http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/guides/jest.html), I think I do not need anything else installed besides `enzyme`. Because thay already pre-configured? Am I wrong?

Comment: It seems they are using jest for the assertion: https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/expect.html#content You can eject the project using 'npm run eject' and then customize it. Then you have more power and control over it. After that you can install mocha if you want. I am a mocha fan. If you need to go with Jest you may need to do some research and fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Shallow rendering won't go as deep as you want in this case because of your `div` nesting. 
http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/shallow.html

Either use `mount` or use `.dive()` API to go one level further. See the example in the enzyme docs:
http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/dive.html

Answer (score -1):

```
it("should render right", () => { 
  const component = shallow(<TestUser />);
  const element = component.find('wrapper');
  chai.expect(element.props.children).to.have.length(3); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

> Use ().toEqual() instead of .to.have.length() as .to.have is not any function in jest expect library
>   [Visit here for more info](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect)

```
import React from "react";
import TestUser from "./testuser";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

it("should render right", () => {
const component = shallow(<TestUser />);

expect(component.find('Card').length).toEqual(3);
});
```